# Handling user entered data with weird symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8

I have a rails app in which a user can enter a comment. Unfortunately, weird symbols can be copied and entered in the comment. For example, when I display a comment, it could look like this:

```
”Test comment with weird quotes.”
```

This comment was entered by the user and displays like above on the view page. These aren't normal quotes, they are HTML `&rdquo;` or `&#8221;`.

Is there any way (through the use of gsub, or a different way) to remove these weird characters from the comments? It doesn't matter if they are permanently removed or if they simply don't show up on the view. The problem is that I can't simply gsub the comment string for the rdquo or html code, as they show up as actual characters within the string. Do I have to first convert the string to UTF-8?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i can se the unicode character for this is `\u201D` according to the code below.

```
string = "”Test comment with weird quotes.”"
p string # => "\u201DTest comment with weird quotes.\u201D"
```

So `string.gsub("\u201D", '')` should give you what you want in this case

Comment: Excellent. The UTF character code is exactly what I was looking for, I just wasn't aware of it. Thanks!